# Not compilable angular library: Unknown error from PostCSS plugin

Tags: angular, angular-library

Trying to build new library in angular

`ng build some-lib --configuration development`

Everything is OK

But when I add some styles to the component which doesn't provided by default in example

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'lib-some-lib',
  templateUrl: "./some-lib.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./some-lib.component.scss",]  // <- by default nothing here
})
export class SomeLibComponent {
}
```

I see next errors:

```sh
Building Angular Package

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building entry point 'some-lib'
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
⠋ Compiling with Angular sources in Ivy full compilation mode.Compiling @angular/core : es2015 as esm2015
⠸ Compiling with Angular sources in Ivy full compilation mode.Unknown error from PostCSS plugin. Your current PostCSS version is 8.3.11, but postcss-preset-env uses 7.0.39. Perhaps this is the source of the error below.
✖ Compiling with Angular sources in Ivy full compilation mode.
Unknown version 15.1 of safari
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1

I fixed this error after long investigation and I understood that I should change `yarn` to `npm` to fix this issue. But it would be great to know what the root-cause of the issue.

### Solution 2

I don't see such issue if generate new angular project. So I created new one, and replaced all files to the new project. Also made yarn package manager as default